# Get the text value of a XML node in R

Tags: xml, r

I'm new to XML in R. Come from a VBA background, there you could get the text value within a node by Nodelist.item(0).text

How is this done in R? I've managed to get a list of nodes but they also show the nodename, but the list doesn't have any XML functions of course.

My code

```
ConnString <- "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.dividendhistory%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22KO%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222012-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222013-12-31%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

     tURL <- getURL(ConnString) 
      x <- xmlParse(tURL)  

  NodeList.Dates <- getNodeSet(x, "//Date")
  NodeList.Div <- getNodeSet(x, "//Dividends")

Output
> NodeList.Div
[[1]]
<Dividends>0.330000</Dividends> 

[[2]]
<Dividends>0.305000</Dividends> 

[[3]]
<Dividends>0.305000</Dividends> 

[[4]]
<Dividends>0.305000</Dividends>
```

Comment: You can try `xpathApply(x, "//Dividends",xmlValue)` or `lapply(NodeList.Div,xmlValue)`

Comment: Thank you nicola! solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a reproducible example, so I can't check my suggestions, but i think you're looking for `xmlValue()`, `getNodeSet` also accepts a function, see its man page, where you can pass in `xmlValue`, and that should work too

Okay, the complete thing is

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
ConnString <- "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.dividendhistory%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22KO%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222012-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222013-12-31%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
tURL <- getURL(ConnString) 
x <- xmlParse(tURL)  
xpathSApply(x, "//Date", xmlValue)
xpathSApply(x, "//Dividends", xmlValue)
```

Comment: xmlValue() doesn't produce the result I'm expecting. Also, combining it with getNodeSet generates error message: no applicable method for "xmlValue" applied to an object of class "XMLNodeSet"

Comment: can you share the `ConnString` object